# Kohana : Kohana_HTTP_Exception [ 404 ]: The requested URL calendar was not found on this server

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3.3

I'm learning kohana and I'm using ver:3.3.0.

I'm getting this error:

```
Kohana_HTTP_Exception [ 404 ]: The requested URL calendar was not found on this server.
SYSPATH\classes\Kohana\Request\Client\Internal.php [ 79 ]

SYSPATH\classes\Kohana\Request\Client\Internal.php [ 79 ]
SYSPATH\classes\Kohana\Request\Client.php [ 114 ] » Kohana_Request_Client_Internal->execute_request(arguments)
SYSPATH\classes\Kohana\Request.php [ 990 ] » Kohana_Request_Client->execute(arguments)
DOCROOT\index.php [ 118 ] » Kohana_Request->execute()
```

URL I type in:

```
(//localhost/organizer_tst/calendar/)
```

My files:

application\classes\Controller\Calendars\Calendar.php:

```
class Controller_Calendar extends Controller
{

    public function action_index()
    {
        $tst = new Model_Calendar();
               echo $tst->testing("LOLLOLOOLL");              
    }
}
```

application\classes\Model\calendar.php:

```
Class Model_Calendar extends Model
{
    public function testing($param)
    {
        $tst ="I want to display it: "."$param";
        return $tst ;        
    }   
}
```

bootstrap.php:

```
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'   => '/organizer_tst/',
));

Route::set('something', 'calendar(/<directory>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>))))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'Calendars',
        'controller' => 'Calendar',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));

Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'welcome',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

I checked "Environment->included files" on error page I can see my controller file:
APPPATH\classes\Controller\Calendars\Calendar.php

Everything is working if Controller is not in an extra directory in this case :
application\classes\Controller\Calendars\Calendar.php

I use Xampp my root directory: D:\xampp\htdocs 
and I have alias to my project:
Alias /organizer_tst/calendar "D:\xampp\htdocs\organizer_tst"

Can you please tell me why I have this error exception?

Comment: Can you include your `.htaccess` file? Also, base url should be a full url, e.g: `http://localhost/organizer_tst/` (Probably not relevant for the problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Kohana's naming conventions](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/conventions) tell you how you should name and locate your classes.

In this case Kohana is looking for a class named `Controller_Calendars_Calendar` in location `application/classes/Controller/Calendars/Calendar.php`. It finds the file but not the class. You should name your class `Controller_Calendars_Calendar` or move the file to `application/classes/Controller/Calendar.php`

Comment: It works now I changed my route:  `Route::set('calendar','calendar(<directory>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>))))',`  `array('directory' => '(Calendar)'))  ->defaults(array('controller' => Calendar_BaseCal','action'=>'index',));  ` and name class to   `Controller_Calendar_BaseCal `

Answer (score 0):

**COntroller**: blog.php
In blog.php there is a method defined as follows:

```
public function action_new()
    {
        $view =View::factory('blog/new');
        $this->response->body($view);
    }
```

**views**:A folder named "Blog" and inside blog you have a file named new.php

Check your files in this sequence.